# Deduction guide needed if outer class is a template?

Tags: c++, ctad

The following code

```
struct some{};
some thingy;

#ifdef OH
template<typename W>
#endif
struct Wrapper
{
    template<typename S>
    struct Checker
    {
        Checker(S  &) {}
    };

    template<typename  S>
    friend
    void check(S& strm, Wrapper const&)
    {
        Checker{strm}; // line 19
    }

};

int main()
{
    Wrapper
#ifdef OH
    <int>
#endif
    w;
    check( thingy, w );

}
```

compiles with GCC 12 and clang 14, as long as Wrapper is not a template.

If Wrapper *is* a template (`-DOH` switch), then GCC keeps accepting the code, but clang complains that it can't find a constructor or deduction guide.

```
<source>:19:9: error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'Checker'
        Checker{strm};
        ^
<source>:31:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'check<some>' requested here
    check( thingy, w );
    ^
<source>:10:12: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'Checker<S>' against 'some'
    struct Checker
           ^
<source>:10:12: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
1 error generated.
```

https://godbolt.org/z/oTTKEcdfe

The difference in clang's behavior between the templated vs non-templated wrapper class is surprising to me. I would have expected the same behavior in both cases (like GCC). Is this a bug, a QoI issue or something allowed by the standard (and hopefully not UB)?

Comment: Clang is apparently still waiting for committee decision on this https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33489#c11

Comment: Damn, I saw that bug before. Why didn't I make the connection?